# Trying to split a string into a few separate categories

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got 2000+ strings in rows of a single excel column. Each cell has a string that follows this format:

"BROOKDALE WOODSTOCK 1000 Professional Way Woodstock, GA 30188 (678) 341-5720 www.brookdale.com"

I'd like to split this string into 4 different categories. I've also included an idea of how I what kind of string formatting I would use as a delimiter.

1. The name of the establishment (which is the part of the string in all        uppercase (BROOKDALE WOODSTOCK))
2. The address (the thing that begins after the name of the establishment and ends with the sub-string "GA 30###" (where the # is an arbitrary digit))
3. Phone number (would begin after the address and follow the format (###) ###-####)
4. The website address (would begin after phone number and begin with "www." and go until the end of the string)

So ideally, from the above example, I'd have a script that'd turn it into:

BROOKDALE WOODSTOCK, 1000 Professional Way Woodstock, GA 30188, (678) 341-5720, www.brookdale.com

Does anyone have an idea how I could accomplish this? Should I export it as a .csv file and do this in Python. Is there a way I can accomplish this in Excel itself? Also will the preexisting comma in the string between the city and state (Woodstock, GA) affect the .csv file? How should I fix that issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that an establishment name can end with a number? If so, how will you tell where the establishment name ends and the address begins?

Comment: No, the establishment never ends with a number. It's just a string of capital letters.

Comment: Do `find` for number to get address, then for `(` then for `www`

Comment: If all addresses are syntactically the same, regular expressions were built to solve this type of problem. Regex can be used in VBA without any magic - if you use late-binding, even better. I can't construct the actual expression, but I am fairly certain that it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your line is in `A1` use these formulas

- In `B1` : `=TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND({"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"},A1)-1))`
- in `C1` : `=TRIM(MID(A1,LEN(B1)+1,FIND("GA 30",A1)-LEN(B1)))`
- In `D1` : `=MID(A1,FIND("(",A1),13)`
- In `E1` : `=MID(A1,FIND("www",A1),999)`

Note this assumes that `GA 30` , `(` and `www` do not apear anywhere else in the string other than where specifird in th OP

Comment: Clever way to isolate the name part !

Comment: Chris,
Thanks for the response! Quick question though - if the name of the establishment ended in GA and the address began with 30 is there  way around that? I don't think there's an instance in which this occurs but just in case.

Comment: @RahulPatel you don't need `GA 30`, just `(`.

Comment: @RahulPatel If you give `FIND` a start position that would occur after the name of the establishment you shouldn't run into an issue with that scenario. So `C1` formula becomes `=TRIM(MID(A1,LEN(B1)+1,FIND("GA 30",A1,LEN(B1))-LEN(B1)))`

Comment: Got it! Thanks for all the help folks!

Comment: Chris, your formula for B1 is actually a little off. It seems to look for the first occurrence of the number 1 instead of any number. How do you fix this?

Comment: @RahulPatel I don't have access to excel right now, but I think you're right.  Solution would be a combination of iferror and min

Answer (score 1):

The following (rough) outline is a "naïve" implementation of what you're looking for. However:

- Given the sparse amount of data provided, it is likely to fail at some point
- This would assume reading "line by line" from a file and I'm not exactly certain as how to convert you excel file.
- There are likely to be a couple of "rogue" whitespaces here and there, depending on the consistency of  the data
- The whole "comma-as-part-of-an-adress-stored-in-a-.csv-file" problem remains unsolved

Here it is:

```
import re

# Input
sample = "BROOKDALE WOODSTOCK 1000 Professional Way Woodstock, GA 30188 (678) 341-5720 www.brookdale.com"

# Split the line around its blank spaces
lst = sample.split(' ')

# Create an empty list for each desired category
part1 = []
part2 = []
part3 = []
part4 = []

# Now to put each element into the right category
while lst:
    # Part 1
    while lst:
        e = lst.pop(0)
        if not re.search("[0-9]", e):
            part1.append(e)
        else:
            break
    # Part 2
    part2.append(e)
    while lst:
        e = lst.pop(0)
        if not re.search("\(", e):
            part2.append(e)
        else:
            break
    # Part 3
    part3.append(e)
    while lst:
        e = lst.pop(0)
        if not re.search("w", e):
            part3.append(e)
        else:
            break
    # Part 4
    part4 = [e] + lst

# For "proof of concept" purposes, join the fields and print them out
part1 = " ".join(part1)
part2 = " ".join(part2)
part3 = " ".join(part3)
part4 = " ".join(part4)

print("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s" % (part1, part2, part3, part4))
```

Output:

```
BROOKDALE WOODSTOCK 
1000 Professional Way Woodstock, GA 30188
(678) 341-5720
www.brookdale.com
```

Comment: Thanks Arnaud! I used the other solution because it avoided having to convert it to a csv but this script looks great! Appreciate the response

Answer (score 0):

If your 2000 addresses all follow that format, you can use a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> s="BROOKDALE WOODSTOCK 1000 Professional Way Woodstock, GA 30188 (678) 341-5720 www.brookdale.com"
>>> pat=r'^([A-Z ]+)[ ](\d+[\w ]+,[ ]GA\s30\d\d\d)[ ](\(\d\d\d\)[ ]\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d)[ ](www[.\w]+)$'
>>> ', '.join(re.findall(pat, s)[0])
'BROOKDALE WOODSTOCK, 1000 Professional Way Woodstock, GA 30188, (678) 341-5720, www.brookdale.com'
```